# Jquery mobile - How to handle click event on body tag?

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

As the title, I want to handle click event on body tag to release focusing of text input. I am using Phonegap and Jquerymobile. Please helps!

Thanks alot.

Comment: At what point and why do you need to do that automatically, every action outside a input field will remove focus, or do you want to prevent input fiend focus at all?

Comment: In my application login page, there is 2 textbox and 1 button. I want to handle the event that user click outside the textfields and buttons to dismiss keyboard. I just think that I should handle the event on <body> or background image

Comment: @Gajotres, could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem? I developed a lot ofapplications with phonegap and jqm and I never noticed the problem which you describe. The blur event fires automatically. 
Anyway you can use this to:
`jQuery('body').on('click',function(){
jQuery('input').trigger('blur');
})`

Comment: Could you give more specific?

Comment: Jquery mobile handles focus on textfields. You don't need anything to hide keyboard when user click outside the textfields, because jquery mobile core handles this behavior.